# Confirm My understanding Determinant Properties

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, solution-verification

Looking for confirmation:
Let A be 3x3 matrix and det(A)=2 then

$$det(-2A) = ?$$
$$det(\frac 1 2 * A^{-1}) = ?$$
$$det((2A)^3) = ?$$
$$det(3A^T)^{-1} = ?$$

So

$$det(-2A) = -2^3*det(A) = -8*2 = -16$$ => Using property $$det(kA)=k^{n}*det(A)$$
$$det(\frac 1 2A^{-1}) = \frac 1 2^{3}*\frac 1 {det(A)} =  \frac 1 2^{3}*\frac 1 2 = \frac 1 8*\frac 1 2 = \frac 1 {16} $$ => Using property  $$|A^{-1}| = \frac 1{|A|} $$
$$det(2A^{3}) = 2^3*det(A^3) = 2^3*det(A)^3=8*2^3= 8*8 = 64$$   Using property $$detA^{k+1}=det(A^k)*det(A)=(detA)^k*det(A)=det(A)^k+1$$

Comment: Thank you! still learning this, but actually was in the middle of doing the clean up as well.